# BATCH,How to search for an specific cmd process(from multiple cmd processes) and kill that specific process

Tags: batch-file

I have 4 cmd processes, I want if there come's an other one I want to kill it and if there are less then 4 processes of cmd running I want to open an other batch file. Some help would be thankful :-)

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. What did you try to achieve your project ?
Look first how to list the number of running process for a special command, how to kill a process by it's PID, how to launch a bash script. Come back again if you don't manage to pull everything together, providing us some code.

Comment: The PID is unique so it will change when you start an other cmd/batch process again

Comment: ONce you get the process list by command name, you can get their current PID with. You work on Windows or linux ?

Comment: @Mofi thanks you so much :-).